# $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $n\geq 2$ . Let $\langle \overline{x}\rangle$ be a proper submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then gcd$(x, n) = d >1$. why does this implies that $⟨\overline{x}⟩ = ⟨\overline{d}⟩$?

I know that $d$ divides $x$ implies that $⟨\overline{x}⟩ \subset ⟨\overline{d}⟩$. But I can't show that $⟨\overline{x}⟩ \supset ⟨\overline{d}⟩$.

Comment: Hint: write $d=kx+ln$, where $k,l$ are integers.

Comment: @Mark I know that $kx \in \langle x \rangle$, but I do not know how $ln \in \langle x \rangle$ :/

Comment: The equality $d=kx+ln$ which I wrote holds in $\mathbb{Z}$. When we take it mod $n$, the part $ln$ simply disappears, because $n=0$ in $\mathbb{Z_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark said it all :
$\gcd(x,n)=d$. So, there exists $(u,v)\in \mathbb Z^2, xu+nv=d$. So, in $\Bbb Z_n, u\bar x=\bar d$. And $\bar d\in \langle \bar x \rangle$. So $\langle \bar d \rangle \subset \langle \bar x \rangle$.

So I would just like to offer an example:
$$n=6, \color{red}B=\bar x=\bar 4, \gcd(6,4)=2,\color{red}C=\bar 2$$
$$\langle \bar d \rangle=\{\bar0,\bar2,\bar4\}=\{A,\color{red}B,\color{red}C\},\text{ with }A=\bar 0$$

By using the isomorphism of $\Bbb Z-$modules: $$\Bbb Z _6\approx \Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_3$$ we can then propose the following illustration of $\color{red}{\langle \bar x \rangle}$:
[image]

Note : $F=\bar3,D=\bar5, E=\bar1$